# Return doesn't output the method to the console

Tags: ruby

When I call the greeter method, it doesn't output the string to the console. I'm having a hard time understanding why. Can anyone help?

```
def greeter(name)
    return "Hello #{name}!!"
end
def by_three?(num)
  if num % 3 == 0
      puts true
  else
      puts false
  end

end
greeter("Michael")
by_three?(4)
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to...?

Comment: I didn't understand the function of return. I thought it would output to the console. Now I understand that it does not.

Answer (score 1):

`return` returns value from method, but doesn't print it. You need:

```
puts greeter("Michael")
```

Also you don't need this return, at all, method returns value of the last executed line.